# Forwarding stdout and stderr to logger in Prefect 2 flows

Tags: python, logging, stdout, prefect

I have a couple of old ETL jobs that need to be adopted to Prefect flows. All of them are utilizing `print` statements for logging. Jobs should be backward-compatible and keep printing existing messaged to stdout and stderr. The issue is that stout and stderr messages are ignored by Orion UI for viewing logs.

**Long story short**, I simply need stdout and stderr messages handled as logger.info and logger.warning respectively.

In Prefect v1 there was [a native option](https://docs-v1.prefect.io/core/concepts/logging.html#logging-stdout) to forward stdout to logger. However, it's removed in v2.

Anything native I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For now I've made a workaround that works fine, but seems pretty heavy comparing to how it was in v1.

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        if message != '\n':
            self.level(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.level(sys.stderr)


def setup_logger():
    """
    Adopt stdout and stderr to prefect logger
    :return:
    """
    prefect_logger = get_run_logger()
    sys.stdout = Logger(prefect_logger.info)
    sys.stderr = Logger(prefect_logger.error)
    return prefect_logger

@flow
def transform():
    logger = setup_logger()
    print('Hello stdout')
    logger.info('Hello logger')
```

Which results in the following log:

```
14:00:10.681 | INFO    | prefect.engine - Created flow run 'pygmy-eagle' for flow 'transform'
14:00:11.075 | INFO    | Flow run 'pygmy-eagle' - Hello stdout
14:00:11.076 | INFO    | Flow run 'pygmy-eagle' - Hello logger
14:00:11.105 | INFO    | Flow run 'pygmy-eagle' - Finished in state Completed()
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to adapt your  code but have a bit of trouble doing so: How does the     `sys.stdout = Logger(prefect_logger.info)` line work?

Comment: @Wingmore hi, default`sys.stdout` is an object for writing messages, so we're replacing it with an object (logger) that has compatible methods and behaviour (especially `.write(...)`). This method is called every time we're calling `print`, so our output is being redirected to the actual logger that does the job

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree that it should be equally easy as in v1, and we have an open roadmap item for that: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/7117

Definitely on our radar and coming soon